# Spring Boot initialization order

Tags: java, spring-boot

How could it be fixed to initialize (create) enities in the DB before `SecurityConfiguration` class will be called?

**1. Simple App**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**2. Entity example**

```
@Component
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {
   ...
}
```

**3. SecurityConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private DataSource datasource;
    @Autowired
    protected void setDatasource(DataSource datasource) {
        this.datasource = datasource;
    }
    ... 
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        ...
        if (!userDetailsService.userExists("user")) {
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use something like `@DependsOn({"users", "authorities"})` in `SecurityConfiguration` but that did not help.
Getting exception from `configure` method because no table is found. If I will not touch db there my tables will be created.

**EDIT: Possible solution**
My first `pom.xml` had such dependencies:

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
```

Adding data-rest dependecy has solved my problem:

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
```

Now tables are created before `SecurityConfiguration` is being called. No exceptions. But still I don't get how (why) does this data-rest dependecy  solve this problem.

Comment: Added about data-rest. I don't why, but it works.